# How to get a single stack from Docker UCP API

Tags: docker, docker-ucp

I'm writing devops pipelines in a Docker Enterprise 3.2 environment.

I am able to fetch *all* `stacks` from the UCP API. Now I need to fetch single `stacks` but the documentation seems to omit completely this resource.

Is there anything as:

```
ucp_url/api/stacks/my_awesome_stack_name
```

or

```
ucp_url/api/stacks?name=my_awesome_stack_name
```

?

Comment: To whom ever voted up this question: THX! I found the solution to my question and I completely forgot to post the answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

The field `namespace` is the identifier of the stack. Calling `api/stacks/my_namespace` will get the desired stack.

#### How I found this

After fiddling a bit with the documentation and the api, I realized that the `stacks` resource is just another collection that can be selected using its identifier.

When you invoke `api/stacks` you'll receive a *collection* of stacks looking like this:

```
[
  {
    "namespace": "my_awesome_namespace_1",
    "services": []
    ...
    "namespace": "my_awesome_namespace_2",
    "services": []
    ...
  }
]
```

I simply tried `api/stacks/my_awesome_namespace_1` and received the desired object in json format.

#### And beyond

I believe the most important thing to this answer is that this method could be generalized to any UCP resource.

1. fetch all resources of a given resource type
2. try to determine which field is the identifier
3. try calling `my_awesome_resource/my_awesome_resource_identifier`
4. cheer up :)